# Consequent jquery promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Right now I have this code:

```
$.when(promise1, promise2).done(this.processData.bind(this));
```

So, when two promises are resolved, *processData* function is going to be resolved. 
Now, I have a 3rd promise - promise3, which depends on promise1 and promise2, meaning that I can only fetch data for promise3 once the former two are loaded. Then I'd like to send all three results to *processData* function. How do I pull this off? I know that

```
$.when(promise1, promise2, promise3).done(this.processData.bind(this));
```

Wouldn't do the trick, because promise3 has to load **only after** promise1 and promise2 are finished.

Comment: Put your second when inside the done of your first when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.when(promise1, promise2)
 .done(function (promise1_result, promise2_result) {

    //Call promise3 having access to the results returned from promise1 and promise2
    promise3.done(function(promise3_result) {

    });

 });
```

Comment: Does this meet the requirement that "promise3 has to load only after promise1 and promise2 are finished"? As written here, promise3's done handler will be attached after promise1 and promise2 are resolved, but promise3 itself will exist prior to that time.